Mott insulating-superfluid phase transition in non-unit filling bose hubbard model
Model I am working with is 1D bose hubbard model with fixed total number of particles. In this model, I am considering total number of particles greater than the number of sites, for example, for the two sites case, max no. of particles a site can hold is 5. and the total number of particles is 5, in this case, number of particles is greater than the number of sites.
I am using the first excitation energy gap to study the phase transition from mott insulating to superfluid phase in this BHM. For the unit filling case of a finite system using the same observable, for tunneling amplitude (J) = 0, and interaction potential U = 1, the gap is 1. This gap decreases with increase in J for a constant U upto the transition point. Beyond the transition point, the gap increases with increase in J indicating a transition from mott to superfluid phase in a finite bose hubbard model.
But I do not observe this for the non-unit filling case, the gap keeps increasing with increase in J. I want to know if this observation is correct. And, if not,  how do I observe the transition from mott to superfluid phase case.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.
